# Ajax .load() with php value from db

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery

Basically i have a value from a database ($learner->idnumber)

I then have a form which posts using submithandler to process.php (this edits database)

Now this is the bit im stuck on, im trying to get the php db value $learner->idnumber to update without page refresh once the form has been processed.

I have found:

```
$("#pinnumber").load("profile.php #pinnumber");
```

but im not quite sure on how to implement this.

This is my code:

```
<a id="pinlink">edit</a>
<div id="results"><div>

<div id="pinnumber">
    '.$learner->idnumber.'
    <div>                

    <div id="pincontent" style="display:none;">
    <form name="myform" id="myform" method="POST">  
    <input type="text" name="idnumber" id="idnumber" size="20" value=""/>  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
    <div>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#pinlink").click(function () {
$("#pincontent").show();
});

    $("#myform").validate({             
        debug: false,             
        rules: {                 
            idnumber: "required",             
        },             
        messages: {                 
            idnumber: "Please enter your PIN",             
        },             
        submitHandler: function(form) {                 
            $("#pincontent").hide();                  
            // do other stuff for a valid form                 
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {                

                $('#results').html(data);                 
            });             
        }         
    });     
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your `data` param from the Ajax call give you?

Answer (score 0):

I included:

```
print "".$_POST['idnumber']."";
```

in process.php before the save to db code.

this then printed into:

```
<div id="results"><div>
```

when form was submitted.